# How to avoid repeating the same verb to avoid redundance

Tags: ellipsis, repetition, gapping

In my point of view, skipping the same verb in one sentence makes it more poetry-like and native.

Here is my phrase:

> The sky is your limit and the sea is your birth place.

Could it be modified to:

> The sky is your limit and the sea your birth place.

I hope you can get the sense of what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Also, although comma splices are *normally* considered things to be avoided, this is a situation where it would likely be considered acceptable. (Because of how succinct and understandable it is.) So, you could also say: *The sky is your limit, the sea your birth place.*

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can do that always.

> Jack swims in the beach and I in the pool

If it's obvious you can even not say the verb. Look at this conversation:

-Where are you swimming in?

+I in the pool and Jack in the beach